# How to update a view from outside a controller in xcode

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, uiapplicationdelegate

So far I have only been updated a view from within its controller.  I am now in a different situation where I need to update an element in a view (a text label) based on some event occurring in another class C of my application.  I realize this is basic but I am unclear what is the proper way to handle this.

- Should I be passing my view controller in the init method of C?  (Seems cumbersome to be passing in the view controller whenever I init that class C.  Would require a bunch of refactoring too.)
- Should I retrieve the app delegate from within C by calling [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] and from the app delegate retrieve the view controller that I need?

Neither approaches strike me as practical or elegant.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two most common methods are delegate and notification.

In one case you give class C a delegate property and set that to be the view controller.  To make it look good, you can define a delegate protocol similar to what's done for a lot of API classes.  It **could** be passed in init but it's standard to just set the property directly.

The other way is to have the view controller listen for a notification that class C sends when the event occurs.  The view controller then makes the update when it receives notification.

Comment: Thanks. It does look like a protocol might be the way to go in my case.  I will give that a try.  I am not entirely sure what you meant by the second solution.  If class C was able to send a notification, it means it would have access to an instance of the view controller, in which case it would be just as easy to invoke a method in that view controller for updating the view accordingly, no?

Comment: No, the object that sends a notification sends it to a notification center and doesn't care who is listening for it.  The notification center just passes it along to any object that has registered to listen for it.  It's even looser coupling than a delegate.

Comment: If notifications are that flexible, both methods you suggested then seem perfectly suited here in my case.  Is there a tradeoff between using a delegate protocol and using a notification that would suggest one method is more appropriate in my case?

Comment: At some point, personal taste and philosophy enter into it.  The sense (almost definition) of a delegate is an object that takes on part of what is most reasonably some other object's responsibility.  When you talk about reacting to an event, though, that's prime territory for notifications.  In spite of those points, there's a lot of code being written that uses delegates just to pass one value.  I'd likely use a notification but I'd likely also be in the minority.  Real helpful, aren't I?  :)